# Minimum circle that cover circular arc

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, computational-geometry

I want to find that minimum circle radius that cover circular arc. here is a api link that i need but i think it is not open source:http://reference.mapinfo.com/common/docs/mapxtend-dev-web-none-eng/miaware/doc/apidoc/com/mapinfo/miAware/geom/CircArc.html

A function should be like that and it will return Circle.

```
public Circle CircArc(double x, double y, double inRadius, double outRadius, double startAngle, double stopAngle)
```

after i will be able to get center of circle coordinates and radius like that:

```
circle.getXCoord();
circle.getYCoord();
circle.getRadius();
```

Is there any api?If not how can i implement CircArc function?

Comment: Do you really need an inner and an outer radius ? This makes it more difficult.

Comment: i have inner and outer radius.with this parameter i want minimum circle that cover my circular arc

Answer (score 0):

Compute the locations of the two endpoints of the outer circle. There are two cases:

- if the arc aperture is smaller than a half turn: the diameter of the requested circle is the line segment between these endpoints,
- otherwise: the circle is just the circle of support of the arc.

Anyway, there remains a difficult configuration with arcs of a small aperture such that the inner arc might pass the circle defined above.